# How to Display blob as image in JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, imageicon

I need some help for displaying Image (blob) from MySQL to JTable. I've research some help that I need to include

```
jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn().setCellRenderer(jTable.getDefaultRenderer(ImageIcon.class));
```

Here is my code:

```
    String sql = "select idcandidates, 
lastname, 
firstname, 
middlename, 
nickname, 
gender,YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(dob) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < RIGHT(dob, 5)) as age, 
position, 
image from tbl_candidates";
try{
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    candidateTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    candidateTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setCellRenderer(candidateTable.getDefaultRenderer(ImageIcon.class));
    candidateTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
}

catch(Exception e){}
}
```

However there is no picture on the table. It just white/blank but when i click on the supposed to be image "[B@147cec" shows

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to set the cell renderer for ImageIcons since the default cell renderer already knows how to display ImageIcons. No, what you must do is to take that BLOB and create an ImageIcon out of it, and how you do that all depends on what data format the BLOB is. If it is in fact an image such as a PNG file, then get its binary stream via its `getBinaryStream()` method and pass the resulting byte array into an ImageIcon constructor, and then add that to your JTable. Be sure that the JTable or its model knows that the column that holds the icon actually holds Icons, meaning you should override the columns `getColumnClass()` method to return Icon.